# DispatchQueue does not wait for async function to complete

Tags: ios, swift, xml, asynchronous, swift4

I'm attempting to create a simple package tracking app that uses the USPS API to fetch data. The *callRestService* method successfully fetches the data and its completion handler *serviceCallback* (which sets the *unparsedXml* property) works. However, the method that I call *callRestService* from does not wait for it and its completion handler to complete before moving on, resulting in my print(unparsedXml) statement returning nil.

As shown below, I tried to use a DispatchGroup object and DispatchQueue to make the function wait for *callRestService*'s completion but it continues regardless. How can I make the function wait for the call to complete?

```
var unparsedXml:String?

public func getTrackingInfo(_ trackingNumber: String) -> TrackingInfo {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.default.qosClass).async {
        self.callRestService(requestUrl: self.getRequest(trackingNumber))
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
    print(unparsedXml)
    return TrackingInfo()
}

private func getRequest(_ trackingNumber: String) -> String {
    let APIUsername = "Intentionally Omitted"
    let trackingXmlLink = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=%3CTrackFieldRequest%20USERID=%22" + APIUsername + "%22%3E%20%3CRevision%3E1%3C/Revision%3E%20%3CClientIp%3E127.0.0.1%3C/ClientIp%3E%20%3C/SourceId%3E%20%3CTrackID%20ID=%22" + trackingNumber + "%22%3E%20%3CDestinationZipCode%3E66666%3C/DestinationZipCode%3E%20%3CMailingDate%3E2010-01-01%3C/MailingDate%3E%20%3C/TrackID%3E%20%3C/TrackFieldRequest%3E"
    return trackingXmlLink
}

public func callRestService(requestUrl:String) ->Void
{
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: requestUrl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: serviceCallback)
    
    task.resume()
}

private func serviceCallback(data:Data? , response:URLResponse? , error:Error? ) -> Void
{
    unparsedXml = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
    //print(unparsedXml) Works correctly when uncommented
}
```

Comment: `getRequest` will spawn another asynchronous task, so your `group.leave` will execute immediately. You should pass a completion handler to `getRequest` and `group.leave` in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `callRestService` will dispatch an asynchronous network operation, so your `group.leave` will be called immediately, firing your `group.notify`.

You could put the `group.leave` in a completion handler, but you should avoid blocking code.  I would suggest you structure your `getTrackingInfo` as asynchronous function that takes a completion handler:

```
public func getTrackingInfo(_ trackingNumber: String, completion:(TrackingInfo?,Error?) -> Void) {
    self.callRestService(requestUrl: self.getRequest(trackingNumber)) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil, let returnData = data else {
            completion(nil,error)
            return
        }

        completion(TrackingInfo(returnData),nil)
    }
}

private func getRequest(_ trackingNumber: String) -> String {
    let APIUsername = "Intentionally Omitted"
    let trackingXmlLink = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=%3CTrackFieldRequest%20USERID=%22" + APIUsername + "%22%3E%20%3CRevision%3E1%3C/Revision%3E%20%3CClientIp%3E127.0.0.1%3C/ClientIp%3E%20%3CSourceId%3EFaiz%20Surani%3C/SourceId%3E%20%3CTrackID%20ID=%22" + trackingNumber + "%22%3E%20%3CDestinationZipCode%3E66666%3C/DestinationZipCode%3E%20%3CMailingDate%3E2010-01-01%3C/MailingDate%3E%20%3C/TrackID%3E%20%3C/TrackFieldRequest%3E"
    return trackingXmlLink
}

public func callRestService(requestUrl:String, completion:(Data? , URLResponse? , Error? ) -> Void) ->Void
{
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: requestUrl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completion)

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the completion of the operation in the `notify`
Simulate a network request：

```
public func networkTask(label: String, cost: UInt32, complete: @escaping ()->()) {
    NSLog("Start network Task task%@",label)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        sleep(cost)
        NSLog("End networkTask task%@",label)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            complete()
        }
    }
}

let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
networkTask(label: "2", cost: 4) {
  group.leave()
}
group.enter()
networkTask(label: "1", cost: 3) {
  group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
 print("task complete!")
 // ......
}
```

you can try this example.

Comment: I think `DispatchGroup` is like `ARC`, `enter()` will `+1`, `leave()` will `-1`, when equal to 0 time, will call `notify`